# Split the numbers with dashes and parentheses (input type with numbers only)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

How could I set my input type with parentheses and dashes splitting in numbers?

```
Number : <input type="text" name="quantity" id="quantity" />
          &nbsp;<span id="errmsg"></span>



$("#quantity").keypress(function (e) {
if (e.which != 8 && e.which != 0 && (e.which < 48 || e.which > 57)) {
    //display error message
    $("#errmsg").html("Digits Only").show().fadeOut("slow");
           return false;
}
 });
```

[example input type](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2QNcG.png)

Comment: Have you looked at the 100s of masked input plugins?

Comment: With that code you would need to add the character codes for those characters. So log the char code and add it to the list.

Comment: mmm... I don't have idea on 100s of masked input plugins yet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Happy Coding :)**

```js
// Used to format phone number and add placeholder and max-length
function phoneFormatter() {
 $(' input[type="text"]').attr({ placeholder : '(___) ___-____' });
  $('input[tabindex="111"]').on('input', function() {
    var number = $(this).val().replace(/[^\d]/g, '')
    if (number.length == 7) {
      number = number.replace(/(\d{3})(\d{4})/, "$1-$2");
    } else if (number.length == 10) {
      number = number.replace(/(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d{4})/, "($1) $2-$3");
     
    }
    $(this).val(number)
    $('input[type="text"]').attr({ maxLength : 10 });
    
  });
};

$(phoneFormatter);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" name="input_111[]" value="" tabindex="111">
```